# How should I make data available to all of my views?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say that I have an app that has multiple `UIView` (for example "tab views"), but all of these views are using the same data to display things, of course I don't want to load it again for each view.

I could transmit the data using segues but since these views aren't really related hierarchically (the data each `UIView` will be using wasn't generated by the other `UIView`), it would feel more logic to me if I had variables that would get their content in the `applicationDidFinishedLaunching` (for example) and then if these variables could be accessible to each of my views.

**How should I do that ? Is there a way that's more recommended by Apple ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare property in .h file, like :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *testName;
```

Form any other class do this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let aVariable = appDelegate.testName
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a *Model* class. A Model represents your data in your app (ApplicationModel), and just that - that is, no views, no UI.

When the app starts, you setup your model object. Usually, the model object is a "singleton".

As mentioned, the application model represents your data in the app. Let's say, the model represents a list of people and its addresses:

```
NSArray* users = [Model sharedModel].users;
NSString* firstName = users[0].firstName;
UIImage* image = users[0].image;
```

Now, one use case of a TabView is that it displays the same data with different views. Note that each controller associated to a tab is a "root controller".

Lets assume view #1 displays a Table View with all users, and view #2 displays a Collection View rendering the images of the users.

In this scenario, each root view controller would obtain the array of users with

```
NSArray* users = [Model sharedModel].users;
```

Note that in a Tab View Controller, the controller associated to a certain tab remains loaded even when you switch to another tab. That is, tabbing to tab #2 for example, wouldn't load the view controller #2 if it is already loaded.

Things get more complicated when the array of users can change or (even more complex) when the objects within the array do change. In this scenario we need a mechanism which *notifies* each controller that its model has been changed.

One approach to solve this is that each root view controller *observes* the property `user` of the shared model through KVO. That way, the controller get notified when the user array obtained from the model did change and the controller can update its current array of users.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your variable which you want to use as a property on your app delegate and you can access that variable using object of app delegate.
For example, create a string in Appdelegate.h file

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *yourString;
```

and access this string from any controller

```
 NSString *string = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).yourString;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't get how to do that in Swift :/

Comment: var myDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate? as AppDelegate;
        println(myDelegate.myString)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a singleton instance class with your shared data.

```
    class MyData {

    class var sharedInstance : MyData {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : MyData = MyData()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }    
}
```

Then in each view controller

```
let sharedData = MyData.sharedInstance
```